# Uninstalling pip from /usr/bin

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

EDIT: ***First I've seen the other pip uninstallation MacOS stack thread and the answers don't help this situation.*** I'm trying to uninstall pip3 from /usr/bin on MacOS

```
which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

When I run

```
pip3 uninstall pip3
WARNING: Skipping pip3 as it is not installed.
```

When I try

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall pip3
WARNING: Skipping pip3 as it is not installed.
```

Finally I try removing it manually...

```
rm -rf pip3
rm: pip3: Operation not permitted
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

Try uninstalling by

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall pip3
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this out one more time

```
pip3 uninstall pip3
```

If that ***STILL*** doesn't work just remove **pip3** manually from **/usr/bin**

```
which pip3

/usr/bin/pip3

cd /usr/bin
```

You can *rm pip3* however you want, but if you want a quick (and painless) removal use:

```
rm -rf pip3
```

You can also do this for any subsequent versions of **pip**

```
pip uninstall pip

which pip

/usr/bin/pip

cd /usr/bin

rm -rf pip3
```